# How do I use simpleproxy?

Tags: server, networking, proxy

Can some one give me an example scenario where this package can be used?
http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/simpleproxy

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question was posted many years ago, but it still appears at the top of Google results, so I think it'd be helpful to add here.  Yes, the manual page is very descriptive, but it doesn't show any examples.  The command line usage is a little better (the manpage seems to imply that the -S switch is required, when it's not).

Basic usage:

```
simpleproxy -L [local port on which you want to listen for remote requests] -R [remote host:remote port for which you want to proxy/tunnel to]
```

A simple example:

```
simpleproxy -L 80 -R some.service.com:9999
```

Running in detached/headless mode (add the -d switch, and you'd probably want to set it up as a startup service if you need the proxy to be persistent):

```
simpleproxy -d -L 80 -R some.service.com:9999
```

You can check that it's listening:

```
lsof -i
```

You should see a line like:

```
simplepro 26317  root    3u  IPv4 86748140      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Keep in mind, traffic in between the connecting machine and the simpleproxy server could probably be sniffed.  If you're connecting to an HTTPS service at the other end, I would advise using stunnel instead.  Or you can try adding the -S switch, but I haven't personally used it.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/en/man1/simpleproxy.1.html) is very descriptive:

> The  simpleproxy program acts as a simple tcp proxy. It opens listening socket on local machine and forwards any connection to the remote host.

From this text, and its option, I can imagine some use cases:

- HTTP proxy
- Connection to a machine in the network which can otherwise not be reached from outside because of a firewall (IPtables can do this too, but requires root)